# Fetch url-data attribute using simple html dom

Tags: php, html, arrays, parsing, dom

My concern is to extract links from a div using php html dom library.

code exemple :

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html='
<div id="base" url-data="http://www.domaine.com/page?user=username"></div>
<div id="base" url-data="http://www.domaine.info/page?user=username"></div>
<div id="base" url-data="http://www.domaine.org/page?user=username"></div>
<div id="base" url-data="http://www.domaine.net/page?user=username"></div>
<div id="base" url-data="http://www.domaine.biz/page?user=username"></div>
<div id="base" url-data="http://www.domaine.fr/page?user=username"></div>
';
```

I need to fetch all domains names from a div then store them in a php array using simple html dom parser exemple :

domaine.com,domaine.info,domaine.org,domaine.net,domaine.biz,domaine.fr

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are the issues you are having?  I will help but I won't write your code for you...

Comment: this is what you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html='
<div id="base" url-data="http://www.domaine.com/page?user=username"></div>
<div id="base" url-data="http://www.domaine.info/page?user=username"></div>
<div id="base" url-data="http://www.domaine.org/page?user=username"></div>
<div id="base" url-data="http://www.domaine.net/page?user=username"></div>
<div id="base" url-data="http://www.domaine.biz/page?user=username"></div>
<div id="base" url-data="http://www.domaine.fr/page?user=username"></div>
';
$str_html=str_get_html($html);
// $file_html=file_get_html($html); // use file_get_html if you parse an url.
$div=$str_html->find("div#base");
$count=count($div)-1;
for($a=0;$a<=$count;$a++){
    $url=$str_html->find("div#base",$a)->getAttribute('url-data');
    $parse = parse_url($url);
    $domain = $parse['host'];
    $array[]=$domain;
}
print_r($array);
```

Comment: find is slow function.  i think better `$divs = $str_html->find("div#base"); foreach($divs as $div)....`